# Getting Parse Error While Using Two Functions

Tags: php

I am trying to write a program using Call By Reference to calculate the area but I am getting a Parse Error :-

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ar' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace.php on line 7`

Now I, cannot think why it is happening?

```
<?php
function perimeter(&$l,&$b,&$result)
{ 
$result=2*($l+$b);
}

funtction ar(&$le,&$br,&$result1)
{
$result1=$le*$br;
}
$result=1;
$length=$_GET['length'];
$breadth=$_GET['breadth'];
echo "<h1><center>Area And Perimeter Calculator Using Call By Reference</h1></center>";
$result = perimeter($length,$breadth,$result);
echo "<br />The Perimeter Of The Rectangle Is <strong>$result</strong>";
$result= ar($length,$breadth,$result);
echo "<br /><br />The Area Of The Rectangle Is = <strong>$result</strong>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled function:

```
  funtction ar(&$le,&$br,&$result1)
  {
   $result1=$le*$br;
  }
```

should be

```
  function ar(&$le,&$br,&$result1)
  {
   $result1=$le*$br;
  }
```

Comment: WTF -_-

Looks like I am drunk <_<. Sorry mate. Please delete this question.

Comment: @PranavJituri you can delete it yourself.

Comment: @Sammitch: He can't, now that this answer is upvoted and accepted.